# Object type is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Following code throws following errors on line with "function(iteratorIndex);":

- must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function
- called object type 'void (MainWindow::*)(QMap<QPushButton*, QHBoxLayout*>::const_iterator&) is not a function or function pointer

```
void MainWindow::ForEachInLayoutMap(void(MainWindow::*function)(QMap<QPushButton*, QHBoxLayout*>::const_iterator&))
{
    QMap<QPushButton*, QHBoxLayout*>::const_iterator iteratorIndex = deleteButtonToIngredientLayoutMap.constBegin();
    QMap<QPushButton*, QHBoxLayout*>::const_iterator endIterator = deleteButtonToIngredientLayoutMap.constEnd();
        while (iteratorIndex !=endIterator)
        {
          function(iteratorIndex);
          iteratorIndex++;
        }
}
```

Any ideas how should I solve this?

Comment: What you have is a method pointer. To invoke a method, you need an instance of the class the method belongs to.

Comment: Here's some really good reading on the topic that should sort you out: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members